# How to debug React Web App hosted on WebServer secured with servlet filter

Tags: reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, webpack-dev-server, servlet-filters

I'm working on an application with ReactJS frontend and Java backend. The build process involves transpiling the JSX to a bundle.js file that is then copied into the backend project, which in turn is packaged as a WAR and deployed to a Tomcat Server.

The normal workflow involves a `javax.servlet.Filter` that intercepts all http requests to the server to see if the user is authenticated. If not, it redirects to an OAuth server for authentication. The response of the authentication is then stored on the http session and used by the filter to allow further request to pass.

So by the time the Javascript code gets executed, I don't have to worry about the user being logged in or not. I just call a rest endpoint `/api/getCurrentUser` to get the user details from the same server that hosts the bundle.js. Everything works perfect in production!

My problem is that I want to debug, change and test the ReactJS code without redeploying the entire application. Deployment takes about 3 minutes and the process is too painful to do for each line of code that I change.

Until the Auth Filter was implemented, I used Webpack's **Dev Server** to host, debug and hot reload the React Code. All `/api` requests were forwarded to a server instance running on my local machine. This is now impossible because when I perform the api call, there is no user authenticated on the backend and the filter redirects the call to the OAuth server. All is lost from here.

[image: Problematic Workflow]

I know this is a Frankenstein of an architecture and it's not something you would commonly see, but I'm all out of ideas how I could make my debug environment work again. I somehow need to get the user authenticated on the backend and use that session to make api requests from Dev Server. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. So it feels like your web back end implements the OAuth flow and issues an auth cookie - is that right?

It then also creates session data and redeploying web static content resets the app and wipes out the session?

Or is the problem that you have to use the deployed redirect URI? Could you just configure 2 values in the Authorization Server and use the second option when developing locally?

- Deployed url: https://myserver/myapp
- Local url: http://localhost:3000/myapp

**PREFERRED ARCHITECTURE**

I often see avoidable complexity when people use server side web apps - which is an outdated concept and causes more problems than it solves. See my [SPA Goals](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-spas/) write up.

Would it be possible to do the SPA security client side? There can be major benefits in performance and usability, and your stakeholders may be interested.

I would aim to deliver 2 components like this  - your React setup would then be totally standard and productive:

- Java Web API (secured via OAuth 2.0 access tokens)
- React SPA (uses Authorization Code Flow + PKCE)

Out of interest my [Java API + React SPA sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/03/24/java-spring-boot-api-overview/) has exactly this setup, or you can run my [online demo React app](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/).

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding - happy to discuss follow up questions.

Comment: > Interesting. So it feels like your web back end implements the OAuth flow and issues an auth cookie - is that right?
That is correct.

Comment: >It then also creates session data and redeploying web static content resets the app and wipes out the session?
It creates session data, that is not available in my Webpack Dev Server.

Comment: >Or is the problem that you have to use the deployed redirect URI?


That is what I ended up doing. I'll explain below.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution by myself. I'm going to post is here in case someone else encounters this problem.

@gary-archer hinted out correctly:

> Or is the problem that you have to use the deployed redirect URI?

I have to use the redirect URI (aka `/callback`) deployed on the OAuth Server. That URI was pointing initially to the Backend Server (as one can see in the initial diagram). So I had to make it point to my Webpack Dev Server instance, which in turn would forward the `/callback` request to the backend server. This way, the HTTP session data gets properly initialized by the backend and the Webpack Dev Server gets the JSESSIONID Cookie in the response.

To startup my environment, I access is `http://webpack-url:webpack-port/login` which is also forwarded to the Backend Server. It in turn redirects to the OAuth Server for login. I could have called the OAuth Server login from the frontend directly, but that would mean to re-implement logic that was on the backend.

[image: Final Architecture]

Comment: Great stuff - a productive developer setup is important and can save companies a lot of money. Good to see you've resolved your main problem.